# TFS 2015 Prevent Checkin via Web Portal

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

The **Code** tab in a Team Project's TFS web portal allows users to check in/out items.  Is there a way other than assigning users to the **Stakeholder** access level to prevent them from being able to check things in via the Web Portal if they have the permissions to actually check into a Team Project? It seems like you cannot explicitly exclude the Code tab form the **Default** or **Advanced** access levels, nor can you define a custom access level.

Our issue with the check in of an item from the Web Portal is that it does not evaluate any check in polices, nor can you associate the object you are checking in with a Work Item. We to want enforce developers using only Visual Studio to check in items into source control.

Comment: Do you have any other questions about the reply above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TFS doesn't provide the feature to stop users from checking in at web page. The workaround it to give the access level for your users.

Here is an user voice about your issue that you could vote and add comments: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/19026091-prevent-users-to-check-in-changes-from-tfs-web-pag

Maybe that you could consider to user Git version control in TFS. In Git repository of TFS, it provide git [**branch policies**](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/branch-policies) that may solved your issue. This is much similar to the check in policies.

Here is a document about move from TFVC to Git: https://www.visualstudio.com/learn/migrate-from-tfvc-to-git/